# Medication switching in pregnancy

Tags: biostatistics, epidemiology, research-design

My study design seeks to answer the following question: What are the potential risks of switching medications from pre-pregnancy to pregnancy for

(1) individuals who switch from medication A to B;
(2) individuals who switch from medication B to A;
(3) individuals who stopped medication from pre to post-pregnancy; and
(4) individuals who did not switch medications at all from pre to post pregnancy.

I am struggling on solidifying the research design since for the non-switchers, if we set follow-up within a certain time window (i.e., after 19 weeks gestation), the outcomes (i.e., hospitalizations/maternal complications) could technically occur before the follow-up starts and more immediate following the "switch".

I originally had a cohort/propensity score design but I am wondering if something like a nested case control would be a better option (or another study design) to avoid things like immortal time biases/etc.